# Polar decomposition of $\textrm{diag}(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Determine the polar decomposition of $$\textrm{diag}(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n)\in\textrm{Gl}(n,\mathbb{C})$$

Comment: Any ideas? In general this is can be found using the SVD decomposition. For this simple case, you can just look and find out.

Comment: Use the polar decomposition of complex numbers for each diagonal element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $\lambda_j=|\lambda_j|e^{i\theta_j}$ where $\theta_j$ is a real number. Then consider $U:=\operatorname{diag}(|\lambda_j|,1\leqslant j\leqslant n)$ and $P:=\operatorname{diag}(e^{i\theta_j},1\leqslant j\leqslant n)$.